# z-index elastic remove after mouseleave

Tags: css, css-transitions, z-index

I am trying to create some animation where my object should be scaled a little than others. And I am increasing `z-index` to move it at the first plan.

The issue appears at the moment of mouse leave. My scale animation ends with a transitions but `z-index` is disappear immediately. And is it possible to make it disappearing with some transition?

**Here is a fiddle with demo :**

http://jsfiddle.net/JJ3v4/3/

I want to "*remove z-index after scale-down end*".

Comment: I had some issue with the fiddle link. I should make it like a code before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution. Actually you can set an initial `z-index` to your component.

In case of demo I've added `z-index: 0` to `.Inside` selector

http://jsfiddle.net/n4buse9u/